# Does Cypher has functions like Group By?

Tags: sql, neo4j, group-by, cypher

I am new to Neo4j and wondering if Cypher has functions like GROUP BY in SQL.

Here is my code:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
RETURN m.title AS movie, p.name AS actor
```

Here is my result from above query:

```
movie                       actor

"The Matrix"                "Emil Eifrem"
"The Matrix"                "Carrie-Anne Moss"
"The Matrix"                "Keanu Reeves"
"The Matrix Reloaded"       "Hugo Weaving"
"The Matrix Reloaded"       "Laurence Fishburne"
"The Matrix Revolutions"    "Hugo Weaving"
"The Matrix Revolutions"    "Laurence Fishburne"
```

Here is the result I want to have:

```
movie                       actor                  num_of_actors

"The Matrix"                "Emil Eifrem"           3
"The Matrix"                "Carrie-Anne Moss"      3
"The Matrix"                "Keanu Reeves"          3
"The Matrix Reloaded"       "Hugo Weaving"          2
"The Matrix Reloaded"       "Laurence Fishburne"    2
"The Matrix Revolutions"    "Hugo Weaving"          2
"The Matrix Revolutions"    "Laurence Fishburne"    2
```

Basically I would like to have the number of actors played in each movie together with the original results.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to review the [aggregation functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/), which you can use within a WITH clause to do grouping.

For example, if you wanted to group the actor names with each movie, you could do this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WITH m, collect(p.name) as actors
RETURN m.title AS movie, actors
```

That said, there are some shortcuts we can do here since you're asking about the total number of actors per movie (see our knowledge base article on [using degree counts from a node instead of doing expansions](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-counting-number-of-relationships-on-a-node/)).

If you wanted to keep a separate row per actor, but also have the number of actors, since we know :ACTED_IN relationships will never go to the same actor more than once, we can get the degree of :ACTED_IN relationships incoming to each :Movie node to get our count. For best performance, get the degree before you expand out to actors:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
WITH m, m.title as title, size((m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-()) as num_of_actors
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
RETURN title, p.name as actor, num_of_actors
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks a lot!